# Query table from another ms sqlserver

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm really not a database person, so forgive me if this question.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and I am trying to view tables on another server database.

Example:

I have my aspnetdb.mdf database, and my anaylsis.mdf database.

What I am trying to do within Visual Studio is read table columns that are inside aspnetdb.mdf from anaylsis.mdf.

How is this done?

Thanks

Comment: just a reminder: please accept answers to your other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have access to any object in other server, you need to create a linked server to that server as below:

in your aspnetdb go to server Objects -> Linked Servers ->Right click  -> new linked servers . 
a window will be opened that you have to fill the information in the general tab  as below:
Linked Server: anaylsisDB
Server Type: otherdata source
Provider: SQL Native Client
ProductName :SQL
Data source: anaylsis(This is the server name which you want to connect to)

After you finished with this tab, in the left side of the page goto secutity tab and fill the information as below:
In the bottom of the page select be made using this secutity content and insert the anaylsis server username and password.

click ok and now you have made a linked server to the anaylsis. so you can use any objects in anaylsis with this format:

anaylsisDB.[Databasename].dbo.[tableName]
or 
anaylsisDB.[Databasename].dbo.[ViewName]
Here anaylsisDB is the name of the linked server that we have made to the anaylsis server.

Comment: One question, where do i find that option for objects?

Comment: When you connect to your local instance, you have some folders underneath your instance name .as an examle
one of them is databases that you have your databases there. Server objects is another folder that is underneath you local instance.

Comment: @ Maryam, i'm confused, i'm using visual studio 2010, the only file i can see in my project ldf.

Comment: Actually my instructions are working just in MS SQLServer managment studio and I am not sure if there is any way to do it  via VS . I did search it in google and the only things that I found were these:


EXECUTE sp_dropserver N'CREDIT_SCORES_CALENDAR', 'droplogins'; 
EXECUTE sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'CREDIT_SCORES_CALENDAR', @srvproduct = N'vm-2cbstest', @provider = N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc = N'vm-2cbstest'; 
EXECUTE sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'CREDIT_SCORES_CALENDAR', @useself = N'FALSE', @rmtuser = N'cdtscr';

Comment: Maybe you need to add linked server in VS by using these sps but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM [linkedServer].[database].[dbo].[someTable]
```

You find some usefull information in  the T-SQL Documentation on MSDN:

> If the table or view exists outside the instance of SQL Serverl, use a four-part name in the form linked_server.catalog.schema.object. For more information, see sp_addlinkedserver (Transact-SQL).

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634(v=SQL.100).aspx#c089161a-53bf-46d4-a2da-51252dd10e3f_c

Answer (score 0):

A useful way to do that is to use VIEWS, you create view with DATAS from other databases and use it like a kind of table in your Database..

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can either setup a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) on the the same server you are running the sp on which will give it an alias i.e.

```
select * 
from Server2.Database2.dbo.SomeTable
```

Or you can use the [OpenRowset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) command. I always try and use the Linked server option although, the OpenRowset is useful if you don't have server admin access.

Both are obviously dependant on the servers being able to communicate ok.